# (2n+1) Orthogonal Matrix with determinant 1 has at least one unit eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose $A$ is any $2n + 1 \times 2n + 1$ matrix with determinant 1

Why would $A$ have a unit eigenvalue; and does this not hold for a $2n \times 2n$ matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from a more basic fact. Try to show the following:

> **Lemma:** If $n$ is a positive odd integer and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, then $A$ has a real eigenvalue.

*Hint:* Consider the charateristic polynomial $p_A(x)$ of $A$ and its limits when $x \to \pm \infty$.

---

Now, for your second question, indeed, when $n$ is even $A$ may have no real eigenvalues. A simple example is given by:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&-1\\
1&0
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The leading term $\lambda^{n}$ of $p_{A}(x)$ will tend to $\pm \infty$ as $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$. Could you elaborate why this shows you must have one real root?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull It's a consequence of the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Precisely. If the polynomial assumes both positive values and negative values, it must be zero somewhere in between by the intermediate value thoerem.

Comment: Ah yes... I was a bit confused thinking it could go complex or something.